# MVC Attendance and Departure System

Tags: c#, ado.net

Hi i have Attendance and Departure System on mvc Using Ado.Net My Connection Name is (DBConnection) i have Two Method One For OnClick TimeIn and AND OTHER one for TimeOut , My DataBase Name LoginTime and My Table is Attendance I have Problem in onclick timein Btton check if row not exist in my Attendance table insert new row else show Message "You Already TimeIn"

```
public void Addtime(Attendance AddTim)
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from Attendance where UserID=@user", conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", AddTim.UserID);
            conn.Open();

            var rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
            bool sat = rd.Read();
            conn.Close();

            if (sat == true)
            {
                SqlCommand updCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Attendance SET TimeIn=@timein WHERE UserID=@userid", conn);
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", AddTim.UserID);
                updCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timein", DateTime.Now);
                conn.Open();
                int rowsUpdated = updCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand insCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Attendance (UserID,TimeIn) VALUES (@userid,@timein)", conn);
                insCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", AddTim.UserID);
                insCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timein", DateTime.Now);
                conn.Open();
                int rowsUpdated = insCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();                
                conn.Close();                
            }
        }
        public void Addtimout(Attendance addtimout)
        {

            SqlCommand UpDCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Attendance SET TimeOut=@timeout WHERE UserID=@userid", conn);
            UpDCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", addtimout.UserID);
            UpDCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeout", DateTime.Now);


            conn.Open();
            UpDCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try describing the problem a bit better? And when will it show that "You Already TimeIn"? And with what data are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more going on then what I can deduce from your question and no real explanation of the error (if any) you are getting. If this is so please post the error or unexpected behavior, and the database schema would also be helpful

I did notice that you are doing multiple insert or update statements in that block, as you are executing each query twice; once as a `NonQuery` and again as a `Reader`.

```
int rowsUpdated = insCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

The original query to check doesn't look to great to me. If you simply want to check for a row count, you could use `SELECT Count(*)`, and execute via `ExecuteScalar()`. This will remove the overhead of a Reader

```
public void Addtime(Attendance AddTim) {
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from Attendance where UserID=@user", conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", AddTim.UserID);
    conn.Open();

    int uc = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
    bool sat = (uc > 0);

    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks You Very Match How To Do if Row null Add Row Else Show Message ( You're Already TimeIn )